Ubuntu 24.04 app Document Scanner : Unable to start scan; scanimage -L works but sane-find-scanner does not work
I installed the Lexmark MB2236i printer and installed the last release driver from Lexmark. The printer is detected by Ubuntu and prints via wifi normally but the scanner does not work. When I scan a document I get the error "Unable to Start Scan". I also reinstalled Document Scanner but nothing happened changed.
I already have installed apt simple-scan more times. I don't have snap. simple-scan regularly recognizes the scanner lexmark.
Can you please give me some help?
I attach the output of the  and <scanimage -L> commands
sgrass@HP-ProDesk-400-G7:~$ scanimage -L
device `lexmark_nscan:libnet/SPECIFY_DEVICE' is a Lexmark Network Scanner
device `lexmark_nscan:libnet/788C773A477E' is a Lexmark Lexmark MB2236i Scanner
device `escl:https://192.168.1.28:443' is a Lexmark MB2236i platen,adf scanner
device `airscan:e0:Lexmark MB2236i' is a eSCL Lexmark MB2236i ip=192.168.1.28, 2a01:e11:2430:380:b66d:c2ff:fe24:7724

grass@HP-ProDesk-400-G7:~$ sudo sane-find-scanner
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Realtek], product=0xc811 [802.11ac NIC]) at libusb:001:007


This question is similar to: Document scanner not found in simple-scan installed from the app store. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It seems to be an exact duplicate of the link posted above
